# Complexity Analysis Interpreter

Tags: time-complexity, computation-theory

Is it possible to write a program that determines the worst case running time of an algorithm in big-O notation? One that would, for example, be able to determine that a single for loop iterating over every element in an array has a time complexity of O(n), where n is the size of the array?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a program X that takes as input a program Y and outputs Y's time complexity?

The answer is simple: It is not possible. In fact it is not possible to even decide whether Y will terminate at all. See the famous [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

That said, there are many things you can do in terms of automating the process of finding the time complexity of an algorithm, and such programs can be very useful. But they can not guarantee a correct answer for every possible algorithm.